# How to Generate a Valid Self Signed Certificate with SANs in NiFi

Tags: docker, docker-compose, apache-nifi, traefik

I am trying to host NiFi securely, the issue that I am facing now is that I get an `Internal Server Error` which is caused by the Self Signed Certificate generated by NiFi toolkit. I use Traefik as the proxy to redirect the requests to the NiFi service and the handshake is not successful due to the unavailability of SANs

Error Message:

> '500 Internal Server Error' caused by: x509: cannot validate certificate for <IP_Address> because it doesn't contain any IP SANs

docker_compose.yml

```
version: "3.7"
services:
    # configuration manager for NiFi
    zookeeper:
        hostname: myzookeeper
        # container_name: zookeeper_container_persistent
        image: zookeeper:latest  
        restart: on-failure
        environment:
            - ALLOW_ANONYMOUS_LOGIN=yes
        networks:
            - apache-nifi-internal
        deploy:
            restart_policy:
                condition: any
                delay: 5s
                max_attempts: 3
                window: 120s
    nifi:
        user: root
        hostname: mynifi
        # container_name: nifi_container_persistent
        image: apache/nifi:latest
        restart: on-failure
        environment:
            - NIFI_WEB_HTTPS_PORT=8443
            - NIFI_WEB_HTTPS_HOST=0.0.0.0
            - NIFI_WEB_PROXY_HOST=localhost:8443, $DOCKER_HOST_URL:443, 0.0.0.0:8443, 127.0.0.1:8443
            - NIFI_WEB_PROXY_CONTEXT_PATH=/
            - SINGLE_USER_CREDENTIALS_USERNAME=admin
            - SINGLE_USER_CREDENTIALS_PASSWORD=ctsBtRBKHRAx69EqUghvvgEvjnaLjFEB
        volumes:
            - nifi_database_repository:/opt/nifi/nifi-current/database_repository
            - nifi_flowfile_repository:/opt/nifi/nifi-current/flowfile_repository
            - nifi_content_repository:/opt/nifi/nifi-current/content_repository
            - nifi_provenance_repository:/opt/nifi/nifi-current/provenance_repository
            - nifi_state:/opt/nifi/nifi-current/state
            - nifi_logs:/opt/nifi/nifi-current/logs
            - nifi_conf:/opt/nifi/nifi-current/conf
        networks:
            - apache-nifi-internal
            - traefik_proxy
        deploy:
            labels:
                # traefik
                - traefik.enable=true
                # service
                - traefik.http.services.nifi-flow.loadbalancer.server.port=8443
                - traefik.http.services.nifi-flow.loadbalancer.server.scheme=https
                # middlewares
                - "traefik.http.middlewares.nifi-headers.headers.customRequestHeaders.X-ProxyScheme=https"
                - "traefik.http.middlewares.nifi-headers.headers.customRequestHeaders.X-ProxyHost=$DOCKER_HOST_URL"
                - "traefik.http.middlewares.nifi-headers.headers.customRequestHeaders.X-ProxyPort=443"
                - "traefik.http.middlewares.nifi-headers.headers.customRequestHeaders.X-ProxyContextPath:/"
                # Routers
                - traefik.http.routers.nifi-flow.middlewares=nifi-headers
                - traefik.http.routers.nifi-flow.service=nifi-flow
                - traefik.http.routers.nifi-flow.entrypoints=$TRAEFIK_HTTPS_ENTRYPOINT
                - traefik.http.routers.nifi-flow.tls=true
                - traefik.http.routers.nifi-flow.rule=Host(`$DOCKER_HOST_URL`) && PathPrefix(`/nifi`)
            restart_policy:
                condition: any
                delay: 120s
                max_attempts: 3
                window: 60s
networks:
  traefik_proxy:
    external: true
    name: traefik_webgateway
  apache-nifi-internal:
      
volumes:
  nifi_conf: {external: true}
  nifi_database_repository: {external: true}
  nifi_flowfile_repository: {external: true}
  nifi_content_repository: {external: true}
  nifi_provenance_repository: {external: true}
  nifi_state: {external: true}
  nifi_logs: {external: true}
```

Is there an option to generate the SANs during the NiFi start-up when it auto creates the Self Signed Certificate.

I am good to use the Self Signed Cert, just want to pass the handshake between Traefik and the NiFi container.

***Note:** I also understand there is an option on Traefik to disable the certificate verification at the global level using the `insecureSkipVerify` which I don't want to do. If this option was possible at the docker container level that would be good but I dont think is an option*

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I'm not familiar Traefik but assuming it's a proxy tool from your question.
The way certificate validation works is that the whole chain has to pass the validation process. If you use the self signed certificate generated follow the instructions of the Nifi Admin guide, the validation will fail on any other system as that cert obviously is not trusted anywhere else.

At a high level, to achieve what you want, I can think of 3 options:

1. Use Trusted Authority to sign your cert
2. In an enterprise environment, create a trusted enterprise cert (your security team probably already have one) that is trusted by the whole network. Then you can use that cert to sign the nifi cert - rather than the self signed cert. Traefik, if configure properly, should also use a cert signed by the trusted enterprise cert.
3. Lastly, and probably not a good idea, is to configure Traefik to trust your self-signed cert

If Traefik is somehow external to your network, option 1 will work. I would also suggest that you find out from them what they recommend.